# pre trained or dataset for refrigator tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

is there any pre-trained TensorFlow model to detect items in a fridge like different kinds of vegetables, fruit, meat, basic condiments? or a pre-labeled dataset?

Comment: This might help: https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/search?query=food%20items%20object%20detection&docid=yUtVUyw4zPJTp%2Bu8AAAAAA%3D%3D

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow** has provided a dataset called ***food101*** for different food classification that contains 101 different food categories.

You may check the documentation provided on their site.

https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/food101